# Shiny Application for Linear Regression with dynamic variable dropdown based on user upload

Tags: r, dynamic, shiny, regression, linear-regression

As the title describes, I'm simply trying to create a shiny application that allows the user to generate linear regression plots based on an imported csv file. After importing the file the dropdown for the variables of interest should be dynamically updated.

As the code below shows, I'm able to accomplish that with mtcars but I'm not able to do the same with an imported files that would have different dependent and independent variables .

Thank you for your help

````
data(mtcars)
cols <- sort(unique(names(mtcars)[names(mtcars) != 'mpg']))
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Build a Linear Model for MPG"),
  sidebarPanel(
    #fluidRow(
      #column(4,
             #tags$h3('Build a Linear Model for MPG'),
              fileInput(
                inputId = "filedata",
                label = "Upload data. csv",
                accept = c(".csv")
              ),
              
              fileInput(
                inputId = "filedata1",
                label = "Upload data. csv",
                accept = c(".csv")
              ),
              
              
                        selectInput('vars',
                         'Select dependent variables',
                         choices = cols,
                         selected = cols[1:2],
                         multiple = TRUE)
              
             

    #)
  ), #sidebarpanel
  
 mainPanel( column(4, verbatimTextOutput('lmSummary')),
  column(4, plotOutput('diagnosticPlot')))
) #fluidpage


server <- function(input, output) {
  
  data <- reactive({
    req(input$filedata)
    read.csv(input$filedata$datapath) %>% rename_all(tolower)  %>%
      filter(driver_name == input$driver_name & county == input$county & model == input$model) 
    
    
  })
  
  
  lmModel <- reactive({lm(sprintf('mpg ~ %s', paste(input$vars, collapse = '+')),
                          data = mtcars)})
  
  # lmModel <- reactive({lm(sprintf('mpg ~ %s', paste(input$vars, collapse = '+')),
  #                         data = mtcars)})
  output$lmSummary <- renderPrint({
    summary(lmModel())
  })
  
  output$diagnosticPlot <- renderPlot({
    par(mfrow = c(2,2))
    plot(lmModel())
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To dynamically select x and y axis variables, you can try the following

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Build a Linear Model"),
  sidebarPanel(
    
    fileInput(
      inputId = "filedata",
      label = "Upload data. csv",
      multiple = FALSE,
      accept = c(".csv"),
      buttonLabel = "Choosing ...",
      placeholder = "No files selected yet"
    ),
    uiOutput("xvariable"),
    uiOutput("yvariable")
  ), #sidebarpanel
  
  mainPanel( #DTOutput("tb1"), 
    fluidRow(column(6, verbatimTextOutput('lmSummary')) , column(6, plotOutput('diagnosticPlot')))
  )
) #fluidpage


server <- function(input, output) {
  
  data <- reactive({
    req(input$filedata)
    inData <- input$filedata
    if (is.null(inData)){ return(NULL) }
    mydata <- read.csv(inData$datapath, header = TRUE, sep=",")
  })
  output$tb1 <- renderDT(data())
  
  output$xvariable <- renderUI({
    req(data())
    xa<-colnames(data()) 
    pickerInput(inputId = 'xvar',
                label = 'Select x-axis variable',
                choices = c(xa[1:length(xa)]), selected=xa[1],
                options = list(`style` = "btn-info"))
    
  })
  output$yvariable <- renderUI({
    req(data())
    ya<-colnames(data()) 
    pickerInput(inputId = 'yvar',
                label = 'Select y-axis variable',
                choices = c(ya[1:length(ya)]), selected=ya[2],
                options = list(`style` = "btn-info"))
    
  })
  
  lmModel <- reactive({
    req(data(),input$xvar,input$yvar)
    x <- as.numeric(data()[[as.name(input$xvar)]])
    y <- as.numeric(data()[[as.name(input$yvar)]])
    if (length(x) == length(y)){
      model <- lm(x ~ y, data = data(), na.action=na.exclude)
    }else model <- NULL
    return(model)
  })
  
  output$lmSummary <- renderPrint({
    req(lmModel())
    summary(lmModel())
  })

  output$diagnosticPlot <- renderPlot({
    req(lmModel())
    par(mfrow = c(2,2))
    plot(lmModel())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: output]

Comment: This is almost what I need. However it doesn't really work for multiple y-axis variables. I slightly modified the script to allow the selection of mutliple y-axis variables by adding multiple = TRUE in the output$variable clause.That allows multiple variable to be selected but more needs to be modified to update the stats and plots.  Would you have any idea how I could modify the script to allow that?

Comment: Yes, it requires modification for your use case.  This just gives you general direction on how to proceed on dynamic variable dropdown issue.  If you have any specific issue on updating stats, please post it as a new question (preferred) or update this question.

Comment: Ok. I've posted a new question instead. It is posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65415824/linear-regression-r-shiny-application-with-multiple-independent-variable-selecti

Answer (score 0):

Addressing the dynamic menu:

Your `selectInput` element must be placed in the server section for it to be reactive. Things in the `ui` section are basically static. Use a `uiOutput` in the `ui` section and `renderUI` in the `server` section.

- ui section (in place of selectInput block): `uiOutput("var_select_ui")`
- server section (add):

```
output$var_select_ui <- renderUI({
  cols <- colnames(data())
  selectInput(
    'vars',
    'Select dependent variables',
    choices = cols,
    selected = cols[1:2],
    multiple = TRUE
  )
})
```